# Add metadata to S3 object using AWSSDK.S3 (.NET)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio, aws-sdk-net

I'm trying to add metadata to an existing object in a bucket. It's actually in Minio but I'm using the S3 client which is compatible. Apparently you can't add metadata to an existing object, but you can copy the object and set new metadata during the copy operation. I can't get it to work though.

```
    NameValueCollection metadata = new NameValueCollection(); 
    metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-MIGRATED", "TRUE");

    var request = new CopyObjectRequest()
    {
      SourceBucket = "bucket1",
      SourceKey = obj.Key,
      DestinationBucket = "bucket1",
      DestinationKey = $"{obj.Key}_migrated",
      MetadataDirective = S3MetadataDirective.REPLACE,
      Metadata = metadata
    };

    _s3.CopyObjectAsync(request);
```

The problem is that Metadata (last line in the request above) is readonly, so I can't assign any new values. I've tried adding it as headers, but request.Headers is readonly too. I've had a poke around the examples in github and can't find anything similar.

Ideally I want to preserve existing metadata from the source object and just add more. What's the correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: Well, this is embarassing. After creating the request, just do: request.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-MIGRATED", "True");